# Отправка POST запроса на Qt

Tags: php, c++, qt, post

Отправляю Post запрос так:

```
   QNetworkAccessManager * pManager = new QNetworkAccessManager;
connect(pManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
pManager->post( QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php")), QString("login=login&pass=pass&open_key=open_key&key_size=key_size").toUtf8());

qDebug() << pManager;
```

На сервере лежит вот такой скрипт:

```
    if (!empty($_POST["login"])&&!empty($_POST["pass"])&&!empty($_POST["open_key"])&&!empty($_POST["key_size"]))
{
    echo "POST data:<br>";
    echo "id - ";
    echo $_POST["id"];
    echo "<br>login - ";
    echo $_POST["login"];
    echo "<br>pass - ";
    echo $_POST["pass"];
    echo "<br>hash_value - ";
    echo $_POST["hash_value"];
    echo "<br>sault - ";
    echo $_POST["sault"];
    echo "<br>open_key - ";
    echo $_POST["open_key"];
    echo "<br>key_size - ";
    echo $_POST["key_size"];
    echo "<br>id_dialogs - ";
    echo $_POST["id_dialogs"];
    }
```

ПРоблема в том что в qDebug'е получаю ответ:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QNetworkAccessManager(0x91c50b8)
content-type missing in HTTP POST, defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use QNetworkRequest::setHeader() to fix this problem.
```

Что я не так делаю? Как мне послать post запрос с параметрами и получить ответ в виде строки?

Comment: Статью читали - https://habrahabr.ru/post/270649/ ?

Comment: Да но там без примера, да и не компилится у меня

Answer (score 3):

Нежели чем пытаться формировать HTTP-заголовки самостоятельно, лучше воспользоваться имеющимся в Qt инструментарием. Классы `QHttpPart` и `QHttpMultiPart` появились с версии 4.8 фреймворка.

```
QVariantMap opts;
opts.insert("login", "my_login");
opts.insert("pass", "my_pass");
opts.insert("open_key", "my_open_key");
opts.insert("key_size", "my_key_size");

QHttpMultiPart *mpart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

for(auto itr = opts.constBegin(); itr != opts.constEnd(); ++itr) {
    QHttpPart part;
    part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader
        , QString("form-data; name=\"%1\"").arg(itr.key()));
    part.setBody(itr.value().toByteArray());

    mpart->append(part);
}

QNetworkReply *reply = pManager->post(QNetworkRequest(url), mpart);

// Не забудьте назначить ответ в качестве родителя, иначе будет утечка.
mpart->setParent(reply);

...
```

---

Несмотря на то, что автор воспроса нашёл приемлемое для себя решение, тем не менее может оказаться полезен листинг одного из возможных вариантов класса, реализующего отправку POST-запросов с использованием Qt.

Файл **poster.h**:

```
#ifndef POSTER_H
#define POSTER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>

class QNetworkAccessManager;

class Poster : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        void finished(const QByteArray &data);

    public:
        explicit Poster(QObject *parent = NULL);

        virtual ~Poster() {}

        const QByteArray &data() const;

    public slots:
        void post(const QUrl &url, const QVariantMap &opts);

    private:
        QNetworkAccessManager *_nam;

    private slots:
        void onLoadFinished();
};

#endif
```

Файл **poster.cpp**:

```
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QHttpMultiPart>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>

#include "poster.h"

Poster::Poster(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
    , _nam(new QNetworkAccessManager(this)) {}


void Poster::post(const QUrl &url, const QVariantMap &opts) {
    QHttpMultiPart *mpart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    for(auto itr = opts.constBegin(); itr != opts.constEnd(); ++itr) {
        QHttpPart part;
        part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader
            , QString("form-data; name=\"%1\"").arg(itr.key()));
        part.setBody(itr.value().toByteArray());

        mpart->append(part);
    }

    QNetworkReply *reply = _nam->post(QNetworkRequest(url), mpart);

    mpart->setParent(reply);

    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished()
        , this, &Poster::onLoadFinished());
}

void Poster::onLoadFinished() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    if(reply == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    const int status_code
        = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    if(status_code == 200)
        emit finished(reply->readAll());
    else qDebug() << reply->error();

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Использование на основе примера данных из вопроса (C++11):

```
QVariantMap opts;
opts.insert("login", "my_login");
opts.insert("pass", "my_pass");
opts.insert("open_key", "my_open_key");
opts.insert("key_size", "my_key_size");

QUrl url("http://www.s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php");

Poster *poster = new Poster(this);
poster->post(url, opts);
connect(poster, &Poster::finished, [poster](const QByteArray &data) {
    qDebug() << data;
    poster->deleteLater();
});
```

Comment: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(0x9903e98)
Это ответ на команду qDebug() << reply;

Comment: Эмм... я вдруг понял, что Вы не имеете понятия о том, что Вы пишете, и как оно вообще функционирует, поэтому оставили столь странный комментарий. Я попробую дополнить ответ с учётом открывшейся информации.

Comment: Нашёл рабочую библиотеку и пример  QCURL v2.0 хорошо гуглится и так же работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл рабочую библиотеку и пример QCURL v2.0 хорошо гуглится и так же работает

```
QCURL cur;
RequestData rd;
QByteArray RequestResult;

rd.Method = CURL::POST;
rd.url = "http://www.s92640jz.bget.ru/register.php";
//----- формирование пост параметров -------
rd.PostData.insert("login","login");
rd.PostData.insert("pass","pass");
rd.PostData.insert("open_key","open_key");
rd.PostData.insert("key_size","key_size");
//---- и отправка файла --------------------
//rd.PostFiles.insert("upload_data","c:\\users\\foto.zip");
RequestResult = cur.SendRequest(rd);
qDebug() << RequestResult;
```